# PG::InsufficientPrivilege at / ERROR: permission denied for relation schema_migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost, database-migration

The following is my `database.yml`

```
development:
     adapter:  postgresql
     host:     localhost
     encoding: unicode
     database: pepe_development
     pool:     5
     username: pepe
     password: password
     template: template0
```

I get the following when I do `db:migrate`

> smaringanti-mbp:xpm smaringanti$ rake db:migrate WARNING: Use strings
>   for Figaro configuration. ["admin", "user", "VIP"] was converted to
>   "[\"admin\", \"user\", \"VIP\"]". rake aborted!
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: 
>   permission denied for relation schema_migrations : SELECT
>   "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:774:in `async_exec'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:774:in`exec_no_cache'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:138:in
>   `block in exec_query'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in`block in log'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in
>   `instrument'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:430:in`log'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in
>   `exec_query'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:891:in`select'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:24:in
>   `select_all'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in`
>   select_all'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:36:in `find_by_sql'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:585:in`
>   exec_queries'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in
>   `load'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in`
>   to_a'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:12:in
>   `map'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:787:in`
>   get_all_versions'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in
>   `migrated'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:954:in`
>   ran?'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:931:in
>   `block in runnable'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:931:in`
>   reject'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:931:in
>   `runnable'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:908:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in
>   `up'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   eval'
>   /Users/smaringanti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@pepe/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace)

Help me out. I am trying to develop it on my localhost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Worked fine finally

logged as superuser

```
ALTER TABLE schema_migrations OWNER TO menuquizz

\q
```

logged as menuquizz

```
menuquizz_development=# \d
                    List of relations
 Schema |           Name           |   Type   |   Owner   
--------+--------------------------+----------+-----------
 public | .schema_migrations       | table    | denis
 public | menus                    | table    | menuquizz
 public | menus_id_seq             | sequence | menuquizz
 public | schema_migrations        | table    | menuquizz
(4 rows)

menuquizz_development=# \q

:~/Projects/menuquizz$ rake db:fixtures:load FIXTURES=menus
:~/Projects/menuquizz$ psql -U menuquizz menuquizz_development

Password for user menuquizz: 
psql (9.3.10)
Type "help" for help.

menuquizz_development=> select count(*) from menus;
 count 
-------
    45
(1 row)

OK
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

logged as superuse:

```
ALTER TABLE schema_migrations OWNER TO menuquizz;
```